# Homomorphism of two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

show that $f:G \ \times  H \rightarrow G$ Given by $f((x,y))=x$ is a surjective homomorphism.

I'm not really sure on how to tackle this homework problem.

So I tried with letting H = $f((c,d))=b$

Then $f((x,y),(c,d))=xb=f((x,y)),f((c,d))$ Hence it is a homomorphism?

To show it is onto I have to show that for every cartesian product of G and H there exists an element in G?

Comment: $f$ is a projective homomorphism, so it is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, $f((a,b)(c,d))=f((ac,bd))=ac=f((a,b))f((c,d))$, so that it is a homomorphism. To prove it is surjective, only show that every element of $G$ can be represented as the result of this function. Suppose $x\in G$. Therefore, $x=f((x,y)).$ It is also good to note that this is not a isomorphism, once $f^{-1}$ is not well-defined.

Comment: so that it is surjective pretty much follows from the way the function is defined? And why would you say that it has no inverse

Comment: A function being surjective depends on many things. If we defined, for example, $f$ as a function from $G\times H$ to a bigger group in which $G$ is included, we couldn't call it a surjection. I say it has no inverse because $f$ is not injective, once that, for example, $f((x,y))=f((x,z))=x$, but $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ are distinct elements of $G\times H$. Therefore, it can't be bijective- and, as a consequence, neither have an inverse.

Comment: Ok thanks that was a good explanation¨